# Update Oracle table from dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, sql, dictionary, pyodbc

I have a SQL Server table (Resource)

| Name | Target | Mean | Max | Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | bb | 3.2 | 4.15 | 1.61 |
| xyz | aa | 2.2 | 5.15 | 0.61 |
| xyz | bg | 2.7 | 4.15 | 1.23 |
| lmn | bg | 3.7 | 6.45 | 2.45 |

And I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {'NAME': ['xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz'], 'TARGET': ['bb', 'aa', 'bg'], 'MEAN': [3.1, 3.7, 2.8], 'MINIMUM': [2.8, 2.4, 1.3], 'MAXIMUM': [4.5, 5.2, 3.7]}
```

I want to update the Resource Table with the dictionary using pyodbc

```
query='''
      UPDATE Resource
      SET Mean = dict['MEAN'],
          Max = dict['MAXIMUM'],
          Min = dict['MINIMUM'],
      WHERE Name = dict['NAME'] and Target = dict['TARGET'] 
      '''

cursor.executemany(query, dict)
```

To get something like this:

| Name | Target | Mean | Max | Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | bb | 3.1 | 4.5 | 2.8 |
| xyz | aa | 3.7 | 5.2 | 2.4 |
| xyz | bg | 2.8 | 3.7 | 1.3 |
| lmn | bg | 3.7 | 6.45 | 2.45 |

I haven't been able to pass the parameters to the query from the dictionary. What is the right syntax to achieve this?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you, it to see the DB writing as a service , meaning to have an a package that will wrap the PYODBC and there you can implement a custom functionality